# Dictionary Meaning of "Modus Ponens" and "Modus Tollens"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, terminology

I wanted to understand *modus ponens* and *modus tollens* better, and I searched for its dictionary meaning.

Wikipedia says that [*modus ponens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) is Latin for "mode that by affirming affirms" and that [*modus tollens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) is Latin for "mode that by denying denies".

Now, English is not my first language, but I understand it enough and these definitions still don't make sense. What does "mode" mean? what is "by affirming affirms"? Can someone better simplify it in English for me?

Comment: I think you want https://ell.stackexchange.com/ for this question. But I can assure you the Latin name (and its English translation) don't make a lot of sense even for native English speakers.

On the other hand, the mathematical definition should be clear enough, if you know that p implies q and you know that p is true then the implication is that q is true.

Comment: See [modus ponendo ponens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modus_ponendo_ponens#Latin) and [modus tollendo tollens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modus_tollens#English), where [modus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modus#Latin) means "way, method".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, *modus ponens*  is that $P\to Q$ is the mode (or justification), by which affirming $P$ affirms $Q$. $$P\to Q, P\vDash Q$$

Likewise, *modus tollens* is that $P\to Q$ is the mode by which denying $Q$ denies $P$.$$P\to Q, \neg Q\vDash \neg P$$

Answer (score 6):

By ‘mode’ it means *deduction rule*, and  ‘affirms’ means *asserts the truth  of some proposition*.

They are the abbreviation of the Latin sentences *modus ponendo ponens* and *modus tollendo tollens*.

They're the deduction rules which justify the following reasonings, in ordinary language:

- if $A$ implies $B$ is true and if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true (modus ponens),
- if $A$ implies $B$ is true, and if $B$ is false, then $A$ is false (modus tollens).